# React function bind в конструкторе не работает

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Делаю приложение на `TypeScript` `React`.

```
interface MessageState {
    editMode: boolean;
}

export class Message extends React.Component<MessageProps, MessageState> {

    constructor(props: MessageProps) {
        super(props);

        this.setState({ editMode: false});

        this.EditOnClick = this.EditOnClick.bind(this);
    }

    EditOnClick(event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLAnchorElement>) {
        event.preventDefault();

        this.setState({ editMode: true });
    }

    public render() {
        return <section className="message">
            hallow <a href="#" onClick={this.EditOnClick}>редактировать</a> 
            <br />
            <br />
            {this.state.editMode ? "Edit" : "Read"}
        </section>;
    }
}
```

При клике на 'редактировать' содержание должно измениться на 'Edit', но этого почему-то не происходит.

При этом если убрать bind из конструктора и сделать вот так

```
<a href="#" onClick={this.EditOnClick.bind(this)}>редактировать</a>
```

либо

```
<a href="#" onClick={(e:any)=>this.EditOnClick(e))}>редактировать</a>
```

Всё работает нормально.

Что-то я не пойму в чём ошибка, во всех примерах такой код работает, может я что-то упускаю. Ещё думаю может быть ошибка в моей версии библиотек.

```
"TypeScript": "2.6.1",
"react": "16.1.1",
"react-dom": "16.1.1",
"webpack": "3.8.1"
```

Работаю в `VisualStudio 2017 Community`.

После долгих проб и ошибок понял что функция `bind` в конструкторе биндит куда-то не туда. Если её оставить там, и сделать

```
<a href="#" onClick={(e:any)=>this.EditOnClick(e))}>редактировать</a>
```

То тоже не работает, то есть `bind` в конструкторе почему-то запарывает функцию, и видимо биндит какой-то другой контекст `this`...

**Добавлено. Во что скомпилировался Message**

```
class Message extends __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_react__["Component"] {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.EditOnClick = this.EditOnClick.bind(this);

        this.state = { editMode: false };
    }

    EditOnClick(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        this.setState({ editMode: true });
    }

    render() {
        return __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_react__["createElement"]("section", { className: "message" },
            "hallow ",
            __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_react__["createElement"]("a", { href: "#", onClick: this.EditOnClick }, "\u0440\u0435\u0434\u0430\u043A\u0442\u0438\u0440\u043E\u0432\u0430\u0442\u044C"),
            __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_react__["createElement"]("br", null),
            __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_react__["createElement"]("br", null),
            this.state.editMode ? "Edit" : "Read");
    }
}
```

Comment: Покажите во что ваш класс скомпилировался

Comment: Добавил в вопрос.

Comment: Чертовщина какая-то...

Comment: А в каком браузере проверяете?

Comment: Сейчас проверил на Yandex, Chrome, Firefox, результат тот-же.

Comment: Сейчас сделал новый проект React по шаблону и этот файл поместил туда, всё прекрасно работает. Значит в моём проекте что-то не так 1. с настройками либо 2. с установленными библиотеками, так как я новые версии ставил, видимо что-то из этого портит проект.

Comment: Вот так... с target: "es5" работеает, а с target: "es6" не работает. Буду пока использовать "es5". Видимо я погорячился ставить "es6".

Comment: Хм, а попробуйте webpack на rollup заменить

Answer (score 1):

Если не биндить то this будет указывать не на класс, а на глобальный объект (window). Попробуйте использовать такую стрелочную функцию

```
EditOnClick = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    this.setState({ editMode: true });
}
```

И уберите байнд везде

Comment: хорошее решение кстати, сам недавно только увидел что так можно

Answer (score 0):

У меня в настройках `typescript` стояла `target="es6"`, и тут есть два варианта

1. Браузеры пока не полностью поддерживают `es6`, и в скомпилированном коде используются неподдерживаемые функции.
2. Сам `es6` компилируется с ошибками. Возможно только при моих настройках, и определённой версии библиотек.

Решением оказалось заменить на `target="es5"`. Теперь код работает как ожидается.

Comment: Это не решение а заметание проблемы под ковер...

Comment: Я согласен что тут нету полноценного ответа, но возможно кому-то такой вариант тоже поможет.

Comment: Сейчас, поясню. Для меня это решение потому что видимо я в настройках для чего-то поставил более новую версию скрипта для компиляции, но реально не знаю насколько он поддерживается, и для меня es5 не как прятки от решения, а реально я просто es6 выставил не подумав, и скорее всего для тестовых целей.

Answer (score 0):

Скопировал в сандбокс, всё работает
https://codesandbox.io/s/lxm36ovlxm
Кстати Вы не задаёте изначальное состояние

Comment: устанавливает он в кторе

Comment: Это я добавил..

Comment: думаю не стоит менять код автора, даже ввиду его неправильности)

Comment: я не возражаю, у меня этот код был в проекте, просто пока чистил до уровня сообщения сюда, видимо код не дожил ))

Comment: И да, я уже точно понял что код рабочий, как писал ранее ошибка была из-за опции компиляции `target="es6"`. И тут есть два варианта, либо просто что-то из этого кода не поддерживается браузерами, так как `es6`  на данный момент не полностью поддерживается, либо просто сама компиляция в этот `es6` проходит неправильно. Вот тут можно посмотреть поддержку `es6` браузерами - http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/, видим что последний `Сhrome` - 97%.